# How to retrieve the original file name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Suppose I renamed multiple files by mistake and now I want change the file name as it was earlier.
example: The original name of file was “Test” through PowerShell we renamed it to “Tested” and again we want to retrieve the original name back and I don’t remember.

Comment: i dont think what you are asking can be done. Hope you have backups.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Windows **doesn't store these information by default**. You can enable auditing for a file (*right click -> properties -> Security -> advanced -> auditing*) to store these information in the future but right now, the answer is: **It isn't possible.**